# What is the difference between these two flow type aliases?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Can someone explain what the difference is between these 2 flow type aliases in a React app?

```
type Props = {
    handleChange(): void, // 1 
    handleChange: () => void, // 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both define callables named `handleChange` that take no arguments and return nothing. Type-wise they are equivalent but as documentation, they are different. The first is a method where as the second is a property that is a function and it implies that it already has a bound `this` where as the first does not.

When using in a point-free context like `element.onclick = props.handleChange`, the first indicates the usage should be `element.onclick = props.handleChange.bind(props)` as it is a method and the appropriate `this` is important. The second indicates it is fine to simply write `element.onclick = props.handleChange` as it is a function rather than a method.

Answer (score 0):

Both are similar. They just typecast to `undefined`.

In first example of code, you're calling function then indicating it returns void.

In second example of code, you're defining a method which typecast is being used in a way that returns a function which returns void.

My personal preference to define like second code example.